# Prevent react-virtualised table with infinite scroll mouse wheel event scrolling whole page

Tags: infinite-scroll, react-virtualized

Using react-virtualised `table` with `infinite scroll` within a large page of content, if the user scrolls to the bottom of the table and the next set of data has not finished loading, the mouse wheel event bubbles up to the window, and the window continues to scroll past the table.

Is there a way to intercept the mouse wheel event to call `preventDefault`? This could check if the user is at the bottom of the table or not and whether to prevent bubbling.

The `onScroll` prop provides some information but not the event and there doesn't seem to be a way to access the `onWheel` event on the grid element that handles the scrolling through props.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept and prevent the event bubbling in the usual way, with a wrapper `HTMLElement` around `Table`.

```
<div onClick={yourHandlerThatPreventsDefault}>
  <Table {...props} />
</div>
<!-- Other Tables here ... -->
```